# How to calculate all treatment effects in SAS with ANOVA?

Tags: anova, sas

In a hypothetical experiment, rats are given four different treatments and the increase in their liver fat is measured. I am being tasked with computing the overall mean and the treatment effects.

The values can be summarized as:

[image]

I first need to present this to SAS so I rewrite this as:

```
data diets;
input factor y;
attrib factor label='Diet' 
       y label='Liver weight';
datalines;
1 3.52 
1 3.36 
1 3.57 
1 4.19 
1 3.88 
1 3.76 
1 3.94 
1 3.64
2 3.47 
2 3.73 
2 3.38 
2 3.87 
2 3.69 
2 3.51 
2 3.35 
3 3.54 
3 3.52 
3 3.61 
3 3.76 
3 3.65 
3 3.51 
3 3.86
4 3.74
4 3.83
4 3.87
4 4.08
4 4.31
4 3.98
;
run;
```

I then proceed with the ANOVA analysis and write:

```
proc glm data=diets;
class factor;
model y = factor / solution ;
run;
```

Which yield the following estimates:

[image]

Now, I realize SAS must be using the fourth treatment as a baseline or something, I really don't want that. How do I compute estimates for *all* four treatment effects *and* the overall mean?

Comment: You can't.  You have to have something to compare things to.

Comment: So I would have to do that by hand?

Comment: You can't really do it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add statement LSMEANS after MODEL statement.

proc glm data=diets;

class factor;

model y = factor / solution;

LSMEANS factor;

run;

You can check SAS manualand add the options to LSMEANS to get what you want.

I think this is what you want (pairwise comparison between treatments). If you really need to compare the treatment specific mean with overall mean, you can use ESTIMATE statement, instead of LSMEANS. But you need to construct the L matrix for the test.

Comment: I also suspect that this is what the OP is looking for.  This is a common stumbling block in R, but usually less so with SAS.